# an isomorphism of dual module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

$R$ is a commutative ring with identity. $M^*={\rm Hom}_R(M,R)$ is the dual module of $M$. It is known that there is an $R$-homomorphism $M^*\otimes_R N\to {\rm Hom}_R(M,N)$.

My question is the following:

If $M$ is a projective $R$-module, $N$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then it is an isomorphism?

Comment: Here is a recipe for showing results on projective modules: first check for $M=R$ itself, then check for $M=R^n$, and finally use the additivity of related functors